# Как убрать рамку из приложения Java?Используется JFrame!

Tags: java, jframe

[image: Рамка между красными линиями]

Рамка между красными линиями.
Я пишу программу калькулятор и чтобы калькулятор выглядел красивее мне нужно убрать эту рамку).

[image: Вот как выглядит таймер без рамки, мне надо добиться примерно такого же результата]

Вот как выглядит таймер без рамки, мне надо добиться примерно такого же результата

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

        Test() {
            super("No taskbar");
            setSize(200, 200);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setUndecorated(true);
            setVisible(true);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Добрый день! Вы можете использовать  setUndecorated(true) при создании JFrame. Тестовый код чтобы посмотреть прикладываю. В этом случае кнопку выхода Вам придется реализовать самостоятельно.